# ReactJs doesn't render second map function but when i update the file it does

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I'm fetching data from an API and using states. At the beginning, I don't get data from API and render the page with using the states with the data I wrote in the file. (I'm trying to say that I'm using static data at the first load). It works well. No problem at all. Then, when I get an input from user I connect with the API, do all the fetching and stuff and update the states. Everything seems normal. Data is received from API, states are updated, no error on console, first map function is rendered etc. but the second map function isn't. But surprisingly, when I change anything in the file and save it (you know that live server updates the page but doesn't reload), it applies the changes that I've done, and it also renders the second map function with using data I received earlier.

My first map function is this:

```
<div id="hourlyForecast">
  { weatherData.hourly.map((item, index) => {

/* ----- I'm getting a long string from API and these 2 lines are to get the part that i need from that string  ------ */
       let startFrom = item.dt_txt.length - 8;
       let iNeed = item.dt_txt.toString().substr(startFrom, 5);

                    return (
                      <div className="hourly" key={index}>
                        <div className="hour">{iNeed}</div>
                        <div className="image">
                          <img
                            src={`/icons/${item.weather[0].icon}.png`}
                            alt="weather-icon"
                          />
                        </div>
                        <div className="degrees">
                          {Math.round(item.main.temp)}°C
                        </div>
                        <div className="wind">
                          <img
                            src="wind.png"
                            alt="wind-icon"
                            style={{ transform: `rotate(${item.wind.deg}deg)` }}
                          />{
                          {item.wind.speed} m/s
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    )
     })
   }
</div>
```

It is working, I guess. After that, I have this second map function:

```
      <div id="daily">
        {weatherData.daily.map((item, index) => {
              return (
               <div className="daily" key={index}>
                    <div className="day">

/* ------ Api gives me timestamp and this function returns me the day in human words :) ----- */
                      {giveMeDay(item.dt * 1000)}

                    </div>
                    <div className="dailyDegrees">
                    {Math.round(item.temp)}°C
                    </div>
                    <div className="dailyDesc">
                    {item.desc}
                    </div>
                    <div className="img">
                      <img src={`./icons/${item.icon}.png`} alt="weather-icon" />
                    </div>
                </div>
              );
            })
          }
      </div>
```

It is also working, it should. I mean, they are not that complex.

So, all with that, here are what happens:

1. At first load I use static data, and it renders the second map function
   [**(IMAGE)** Rendered component with static data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUw2a.png)
2. When I enter an input it triggers the API Call, and it should re-render, but it does **not** [**(IMAGE)** Empty Component even though API Call works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MhAJ.png)
3. But when I change anything in the file after the API Call and save it, live server updates and the second map function is rendered. Let's say I change "°C" in the second map function with "°F" and save it. Then, everything works. [**(IMAGE)** File updated without page being reloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL5Dj.png)

I guess that's all I can say. I just don't understand the problem. Surely would appreciate any help.

Here is the part that I do the API stuff: (It can be a mess 'cause gotta do 3 API calls and didn't want to use async function due to my lack of experience with it)

```
var datam = {};

const work = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      fetch(
        `${ApiUrl}weather?q=${e.target.cityName.value}&appid=${ApiKey}&units=metric&lang=en`
      )
        .then((data) => {
          return data.json();
        })
        .then((gelen) => {
          console.log(gelen);
          if (gelen.cod === 200) {
            datam = {
              degrees: Math.round(gelen.main.temp),
              description: gelen.weather[0].description,
              feels_like: gelen.main.feels_like,
              city: `${e.target.cityName.value}, ${gelen.sys.country}`,
              min: gelen.main.temp_min,
              max: gelen.main.temp_max,
              icon: gelen.weather[0].icon,
              lat: gelen.coord.lat,
              lon: gelen.coord.lon,
            };
          } else {
            alert("Couldn't get the data");
          }
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log(datam);
          fetch(
            `${ApiUrl}forecast?lat=${datam.lat}&lon=${datam.lon}&units=metric&appid=${ApiKey}&lang=en`
          )
            .then((fivedays) => fivedays.json())
            .then((veri) => {
              console.log(veri);
              datam.hourly = [];
              if (veri.cod === "200") {
                for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                  datam.hourly[i] = veri.list[i];
                }
                console.log(datam);
              }
            })
            .then(() => {
              datam.daily = [];
              fetch(
                `${ApiUrl}onecall?lat=${datam.lat}&lon=${datam.lon}&exclude=current,hourly,minutely,alerts&units=metric&appid=${ApiKey}&lang=en`
              )
                .then((donus) => donus.json())
                .then((yanit) => {
                  console.log(yanit);
                  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    datam.daily[i] = {};
                    datam.daily[i]["temp"] = yanit.daily[i + 1].temp.day;
                    console.log("1");
                    datam.daily[i].desc =
                      yanit.daily[i + 1].weather[0].description;
                    datam.daily[i].icon = yanit.daily[i + 1].weather[0].icon;
                    datam.daily[i].dt = yanit.daily[i + 1].dt;
                  }
                });
            })
            .then(() => {
              console.log(datam);
// ------------ weatherData is the main state I'm using -----------
              setWeatherData(datam);

// ------------ searched state is the important for only the first load. If they do the search i change what is being rendered -----------
              setSearched(true);
            });
          //
        });
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  };
```

The problem is this here: [**(VIDEO)** Everything Works but doesn't appear until VS Code recompile](https://youtu.be/T4Q-PIrl_Zg)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you also share the part of the code where you are doing the API call and setting your states with the data coming from it?

Comment: I added that part also.  Sorry if it is a bit of a mess, but I need to get the "lat" and "lon" and other stuff from the first call and do the other 2 call with using lat and lon data. So, it is lots of "then()"s. I'm now curious if the problem is the performance.

Comment: Few things. The first one, you should split your API fetch function into smaller ones, this will be easier to read and debug. Second, `fetch` doesn't throw errors unless it's a Network error. You have to do it yourself checking for the `ok` status of the response. Third, since you are using promise chaining, you don't need `try` `catch` blocks. Just use `.then` `.catch` and maybe `.finally`.

Comment: Yeah, definitely would be easier if they were smaller functions, and they actually were :) Since I couldn't understand the problem I tried to rewrite them as the most basic, maybe longer but more familiar way.  For the error part, I'm looking for the “cod” from the API call to be “200” as an “ok” status. You're probably right about the try-catch part.  But after all that, I can't see any major issue about API Call that can cause the render problem. Do you think that changing the last function can fix this?